# Extending $K$-theory classes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $X$ be a $G$-space, for a compact Lie group $G$. If $U\subset X$ is a $G$-invariant open subspace, is it true that the restriction map on equivariant $K$-theory $$K_G(X)\rightarrow K_G(U)$$ is always surjective?

Comment: Let $G$ be the trivial group, $X=\mathbb{C}$ and $U=\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus\{0\}$. Then $K(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ but $K(U)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$ and the map is just the inclusion of the first factor.